# Best design pattern for public/sharable routes containing some sensitive data

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, react-router, firebase-security

A manager needs to make the team's schedule live/public. The main challenge I'm running into is my firebase db security rules require users to be logged it in order to read data from it. They sort of look like this:

```js
{
  "rules": {  
    .read:true,
    .write:true
  }
    "profiles":{
      ".read": true,
     ".write": true
    },
     "$clinicId":{
      ".write":"root.child($clinicId).child('permissions').child('admins').child(auth.uid).val() == true",
        ".read": "root.child($clinicId).child('permissions').child('members').child(auth.uid).val() == true"
    }
  }
}
```

What comes to my head is the following:
1- When the manger publishes the schedule, I would generate a token, add it to my permissions rules, and embed the token in the shared url as a param.
2- Then when an employee tries to access the url, I would use the token to sign in the user into the app.

I have explored claims and tokens in Firebase and I'm not quite sure which one would be the best neither this is a correct approach.

I would appreciate any insights.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it sounds like you want to make the data public, but harder to access.
Why don't you just include the id of the public doc in the url ? It is already a big-hard-to-guess hash. Which is all you'd be doing.

Additional security might include:

- keep public docs separate from private ones, different collections
- or use a flag on the doc that you can check the "visibility" of before returning to the client

Comment: thank you for your insights. I ended up implementing your first suggestion. Cheers